# ARC ownership with strong and weak references

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

In apples example

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];

MyViewController * __weak weakMyController = myController;
myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;
    if (strongMyController) {

        [strongMyController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else {
        // Probably nothing...
    }
};
```

What is happening here?  I'm confused about:
MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;

Does that mean weakMyController has a strong reference to it, so it would be like weakMyController's retain count + 1?  What happens when you create a strong reference to a weak iVar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean weakMyController has a strong reference to it, so it
>   would be like weakMyController's retain count + 1?

The retain count for myController is the same for all the variables that have its reference. It's a value of the object, not of the variables pointing to it. And it tells the runtime ho many strong references there exist pointing to the object.

So, the line

```
 MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;
```

will increment that count by 1, and ensure that as long as we have that variable in scope, that view controller won't be released.

In most cases it's enough to call methods on the weak reference inside the block (`weakMyController` in your example). I think that in this case they use a strong reference because there's an animation involved (so the view controller needs to exist for the duration of the animation, which would not be guaranteed if we used a weak reference).

To respond to the other part of your question, all the strong and weak references to an object hold the same value (the memory address of the object). The difference between strong and weak is what happens when they get their values. In the case of a weak reference, the retain count stays the same, while with a strong reference it gets incremented.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain why doing that wouldn't cause a retain cycle?  It seems like since strongMyController would cause a retain cycle because strongMyController is now an owner to weakMyController which points to myController.

Comment: Because weakMyController does not increment the retain count in any way.  It is the same reason why weak delegates do not create retain cycles.

Comment: Good question! A retain cycle would happen if anywhere in your block you had a line using an existing strong reference to myController. Yes, you do create a new strong reference in the block, but it only gets created when the block is executed, and by that time myController might cease to exist, and `strongMyController` will then be nil. So, no retain cycle here.

Comment: Thanks @BlackRider for the explanation.  So just to make sure I'm understanding this right: Because strongMyController is created in the block it will only exist within the lexical scope of the block so after the block is done executing that additional retain count from strongMyController will be decremented. In addition strongMyController will hold on to myController for the duration of the block as long as myController exists when the block is executed.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And in addition, in your specific example, I believe that `strongMyController` will hold on to `myController` for as long as `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` is running (it may still be running when you exit the block).